# Cylinder Work Problem Calculus

Tags: calculus, volume

"Suppose it takes $k$ units of energy to lift a cubic meter of water one meter. About how much energy $E$ will take to remove all water from a cylinder with one meter in diameter and 100 meters deep? (Answer should depend on $k$.)"

It looks pretty straightforward but I encounter one problem.

So as I understood

$E = k*\frac{V}{h}$ where V is the volume and h is the height.

substituting for volume we get

$$E = k\frac{\Pi}{4h}dh$$

after setting integral from 0 to 100 and solving I get

$$ k\frac{\Pi}{4}(ln(100) - ln(0))$$

and obviously ln(0) is undefined.

Can you please point out what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost a factor $h$ because of the distance you must lift the volume.  If $A$ is the cross sectional area, a small unit of volume is $dV=Adh$.  If we measure $h$ with $0$ at the top of the tank and increasing downward, the small unit of volume at coordinate $h$ takes $dE=khdV=khAdh$ to remove it.  Now you can integrate over $h$ from $0$ to $100$.  You get something in $h^2$, which is reasonable because the average bit of water gets lifted $\frac h2$ and you have $h$ height of water.

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean that $ E = V*h$ instead of $E = \frac{V}{h}$?

Comment: Yes.  $V$ is the mass you are lifting and $h$ is the distance you lift it.  The energy is the product of these (with a constant $\rho g$ that is absorbed in your $k$)

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

the energy needed to lift one cubic meter of water for 1m is
$E=mgh=ke\Rightarrow e=\frac{mgh}{k}=\frac{\rho \cdot g}{k}\Rightarrow \rho \cdot g=e\cdot k$

Removing water from the reservoir is similar with bringing up cylindrical volumes of height dy located at depth y.

so the mass to lift is $dm=\rho\cdot \pi\cdot R^2\cdot dy$

the energy required to remove that mass is $dE = dm\cdot g\cdot y=$

the total energy spent is $E=\int_{0}^{h}dE=\rho\cdot\pi\cdot R^2\cdot g \cdot[\frac{y^2}{2}]_{0}^{h}=\rho\cdot\pi\cdot (0.5)^2\cdot g \cdot\frac{100^2}{2}=k\cdot e\cdot\pi \cdot \frac{10000}{8}=1250\cdot \pi\cdot k$ units of energy

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explicit answer.